# Angular deployment on Azure

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

I am dealing with my first deployment of Angular app. My app has multiple routes, API calls etc. I already deployed NET Core API on Azure. Now for Angular I am not sure what to use, is static website deployment okey? I can use Storage or Static Website for that and another option is App Service which is a bit pricey.

I understand what static website means, but is that same to dist folder of Angular build?

I know there are many guides on internet, but all do it a bit different and I can't decided what is the right way in 2020.
Thanks for any input on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Options for hosting SPA websites (angular)

1. App Service - If you already have APIs, then there is no additional cost as you pay for App Service Plan (not App Service). if you use this, you gain all the benefits of App Service like Slots etc
2. Storage - It works well to use Blob Storage to host static websites. But, you don't get the features that you have in App Service
3. A recent addition to this is Azure App Service - Static Websites - It's still in preview (I guess). it's not recommended until it goes to production.